# My PS4 won’t connect to controllers unless using a usb cord

Tags: controllers

I thought I just needed a new controller until I bought one and I found out the problem is my PS4 any recommendations for how to fix this problem

Comment: Can you provide more information about your controllers, PS4 and USB cord?

Comment: It is an original PS4 from 2014 and the first controller I started having problems with was a clear one I bought earlier this year and and the second one was a glacier white one I bought last week other than this issue the PlayStation work perfectly fine usb cord was the one that came with a PlayStation classic